# nose.tools.eq_ vs assertEqual

Tags: python, testing, nose, python-unittest, assertion

**The Problem:**

We've been using `nose` test runner for quite a while.

From time to time, I see our tests having `eq_()` calls:

```
eq_(actual, expected)
```

instead of the common:

```
self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

**The question:**

Is there any benefit of using `nose.tools.eq_` as opposed to the standard unittest framework's `assertEqual()`? Are they actually equivalent?

---

**Thoughts:**

Well, for one, `eq_` is shorter, but it has to be imported from `nose.tools` which makes the tests dependent on the test runner library which can make it more difficult to switch to a different test runner, say `py.test`. On the other hand, we are also using `@istest`, `@nottest` and `@attr` nose decorators a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They aren't equivalent to `unittest.TestCase.assertEqual`.

> **`nose.tools.ok_(expr, msg=None)`**
>
> > Shorthand for `assert`. Saves 3 whole characters!
>
> **`nose.tools.eq_(a, b, msg=None)`**
>
> > Shorthand for `assert a == b, "%r != %r" % (a, b)`

https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.ok_

These docs are however slightly misleading. If you check the source you'll see `eq_` actually is:

```
def eq_(a, b, msg=None):
    if not a == b:
        raise AssertionError(msg or "%r != %r" % (a, b))
```

https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/tools/trivial.py#L25

This is pretty close to the base case of `assertEqual`:

```
def _baseAssertEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):
    """The default assertEqual implementation, not type specific."""
    if not first == second:
        standardMsg = '%s != %s' % _common_shorten_repr(first, second)
        msg = self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg)
        raise self.failureException(msg)  # default: AssertionError
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9b5ef19c937bf9414e0239f82aceb78a26915215/Lib/unittest/case.py#L805

However, as hinted by the docstring and function name, `assertEqual` has the potential of being *type-specific*. This is something you lose with `eq_` (or `assert a == b`, for that matter). `unittest.TestCase` has special cases for `dict`s, `list`s, `tuple`s, `set`s, `frozenset`s and `str`s. These mostly seem to facilitate prettier printing of error messages.

But `assertEqual` is a class member of `TestCase`, so it can only be used in `TestCase`s. `nose.tools.eq_` can be used wherever, like a simple `assert`.